# Using regex extract string from a line in python

Tags: python, regex

I have such types of sentences,

"Hello world, Hi[12312]
234 32423 234
23423 232 23423
2223 234 23234
223 2332 2323
I am a programmer, How[54321]
23 2 12 112
12 1212 121
This is a program, Okay[123123] 12123
1232 12312 1231
323 123 23423
...this continues"

I would like to get all the string until '['

My output should be
"Hello world, Hi
I am a programmer, How
This is a program, Okay"   `

How can I do this using regex?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? This is not a coding as service platform.

Comment: That looks like you're actually trying to get the string up to `[`, not `,`.

Comment: `.split('[')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions for this, you could just use split to split on `'['`, and then take the first returned item.

```
line1 = "Hello world, Hi[12312]"
line2 = "I am a programmer, How[54321]"

print(line1.split('[')[0])
print(line2.split('[')[0])
```

Produces:

```
Hello world, Hi
I am a programmer, How
```

**EDIT**

To loop through all lines, and only print those that have '[':

```
string1 = '''Hello world, Hi[12312] 234 32423 234
23423 232 23423
2223 234 23234
223 2332 2323
I am a programmer, How[54321]
23 2 12 112
12 1212 121
This is a program, Okay[123123] 12123
1232 12312 1231
323 123 23423'''

lines = string1.split('\n')

for line in lines:
    if '[' in line:
        print(line.split('[')[0])
```

Prdouces:

```
Hello world, Hi
I am a programmer, How
This is a program, Okay
```

Comment: I just added an edit to my post that can deal with the edited problem.